# What do these parts of this PCB do?

Tags: pcb, identification, high-frequency

Here is an image of an [LNB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_block_downconverter) circuit:

[image]

There is some parts in this circuit that I cannot know what they are. Marked them using blue circles. What are these parts and what do they do?

They looks like the [Crest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_(heraldry)) of Roman [Gelea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galea_(helmet)) :)

Comment: Dave Jones (EEVBlog) sometimes does teardowns of equipment with this kind of feature... https://youtu.be/1QBFIfKlvHU?t=3003   You often find these in high frequency circuitry, particularly things like oscilloscopes, spectrum analysers etc.  I believe they are used as a convenient way to provide passive filtering components (capacitors, inductors and resistors) by using copper shapes instead of soldered-down components.

Comment: See: Bowtie stub :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stub_(electronics)#Radial_stub

Comment: One very useful aspect of using these copper shapes instead of discrete components is that they have **extremely** good tolerance repeatability from one product to the next - typically much less than 1% variation between PCBs of the same type.  Contrast that with a surface mount capacitor - even a good quality brand might vary +/- 10% from one to the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a microstrip [radial stub](http://www.antennamagus.com/database/antennas/antenna_page.php?id=292) these are used for impedance matching when a low-impedance stub is needed. Their shape allows for a narrow connection point to the main microstrip.

When used in pairs these are also known as butterfly stubs, or bowtie stubs.

As any other stub, these are used to match the input/output impedance of a circuit element to another, to maximize power transfer and minimize reflections. These also “tune” a microstrip, as their impedance-matching characteristics is wavelength-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Those "V" shaped pieces of metal are impedance-transformers.

They serve as large areas, to provide bypassing.